# How to subtract control and experimental graph network?

Tags: statistics, graph-theory

This is more of a theory question. I'm looking into using graph theory to analyze the expression of proteins across brain regions. I have 8 experimental brains and 8 control brains (structured in a .csv file where each row represents a brain and each column a brain region with the value of each cell being the quantity of protein expressing cells). Currently, I am analyzing this data by creating a graph out of the relationship of expression of protein between regions (correlation matrix) for the control brains and experimental brains and then comparing the structure between these groups. I was wondering if it would be sound to subtract the expression of proteins in control brains to that of experimental in order to create a graph network from the relationship in fold change between brain regions? And if so, what would be a statistically fair way to subtract these, would I randomize the subtraction of the 8 control and 8 experimental brains and create a graph from that, so that I have 8 randomized resulting rows or should I subtract every iteration possible so 8^2 and create a graph from that?